# How to fix the columns width in a table

Tags: tables

I tired a lot with the following code but always i get unequal size of columns { I need columns (2-end) of the same width.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|p{8cm}|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline

\textbf{Subject} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{\textbf{First year}} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{\textbf{Second year}} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{\textbf{Third year}} \\ \hline
Literature survey on stochastic geometry, heterogeneous cellular networks, caching system, and interference mitigation techniques in cellular networks  & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Develop interference mitigation technique for the single tier caching system &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Study the trade-off between the achievable hit probability gain and the overhead &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Extend the study to heterogeneous cache-enabled cellular network and propose an interference suppression technique for both cross tier and intercell interference &  &  &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Study the analysis with introducing cognitive cache-enabled users tier scenario &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} &  &  \\ \hline
Extracting the final recommendations depending on the research conclusions  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `tabularx` environment instead of just the `tabular` to benefit from all `\textwidth` while having equal-width columns at the same time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl,tabularx}     
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{8cm}|*{12}{X|}}
\hline
\textbf{Subject} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{\textbf{First year}} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{\textbf{Second year}} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{\textbf{Third year}} \\ \hline
Literature survey on stochastic geometry, heterogeneous cellular networks, caching system, and interference mitigation techniques in cellular networks  & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Develop interference mitigation technique for the single tier caching system &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Study the trade-off between the achievable hit probability gain and the overhead &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Extend the study to heterogeneous cache-enabled cellular network and propose an interference suppression technique for both cross tier and intercell interference &  &  &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Study the analysis with introducing cognitive cache-enabled users tier scenario &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} &  &  \\ \hline
Extracting the final recommendations depending on the research conclusions  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} & \cellcolor[HTML]{656565} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]